# App logo not getting surfaced

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I've a msal/v2-endpoint web app registered (apps.dev.microsoft.com).
I have also specified a custom app logo, privacy statement and terms of service urls.

The custom app logo is not getting surfaced in the Office 365 portal beside the app - just the boilerplate app logo. Likewise it is not surfaced on the application access panel (https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications).

Is this a bug or feature not implemented yet?

Also where should we expect the privacy and terms urls to be surfaced?

Thanks, Donal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug and the teams that own these portals are evaluating a fix.

Regarding terms of service and privacy statement: you can expect these URLs to be surfaced on the consent screen for your application.